# Any ideas how I could get people to participate in my live Internet application experiment for my thesis?

Tags: research-process, computer-science, thesis, collaboration, networking

I have developed an Internet application that I need people to run across the Internet to collect statistics to see how well the program works.  So far, I have used LinkedIn to reach out to my friends from my university and I started an open group.  I also have a Git page where the program can be downloaded.

http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Andrew-Stantons-WSU-Masters-Thesis-6518497?home=&gid=6518497&trk=groups_guest_most_popular-h-logo

https://github.com/acstanton515/ThesisLiveExperiment

I don't think the participation is going to be what I would like, so I need a way to find more users willing to run the program.

Any ideas on how to reach others in academia or elsewhere on a broader level?

Comment: Well played - you managed to ask a relevant question *and* plug some shameless self-advertising at the same time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready to invest a small sum, Amazon Mechanical Turk https://www.mturk.com/mturk/ might be a good place to look.

Comment: Wow this looks cool.  I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

First: If you intend to do research, you have to pay attention to how you pick the participants. If you just take everyone willing to participate, there could be age/gender/etc bias in your results.

Answer to actual question: Standard way to do this is to pay your participants (though not necessarily in cash). Try movie tickets etc.